# How does AngularJS controller handle the res.json(false) value?

Tags: javascript, api, angularjs, express

I have an AngularJS controller that makes an HTTP get request to an API. The API can either return a `res.json(true)` or a `res.json(false)` value based on some condition.

However, the controller seems to be ignoring this and I'm just curious to see how someone else would implement this:

```
function MyCtrl($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('/api/call').
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      console.log(data); // --> this prints out false
      if (data) { // --> this evaluates and I'd expect this to fail, however
        console.log("true"); --> this also shown
      }
    });
```

1. Should I modify my response from the api that it returns something else other than res.json(false)?
2. Should I modify the code above to say something like `if (data === false)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
res.json(true) // not JSON
res.json({ status: true }) // JSON
```